# is this integral proof legit?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

$\int f(u(x))du(x) = [u(x)=s , u'(x)dx = ds  ] = \int f(s) ds = F(s) +c = F(u(x))+c$

Comment: yes it's correct.

Comment: It's correct, although I'd write the starting point as $\int f(u(x))u'(x)\,dx$

Comment: i know but that how it was given in the textbook

Comment: Maybe that $\int f(u(x))\,du(x)$ was a Stieltjes integral?  It could be meaningful even if $u'(x)$ fails to exist at some points.  And (with proper hypotheses) the formula shown is still correct.  But not the proof using $u'(x)$ of course.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little awkwardly stated, since $ [u(x)=s , u'(x)dx = ds  ] $ is just a description of what one is going to do, and is very much not equal to the things before or after it.

But yes, the idea *is* sound. You're introducing a new scalar $s$ which is subject to the identity $s = u(x)$, which simplifies the expression making it easier to see that $y = F(s)$ is a solution to the equation $\mathrm{d}y = f(u(x)) \mathrm{d}u(x)$.

Alas, thinking of things this way requires some comfort with the idea of expressing things through dependent variables rather than through functions, and of manipulating differentials (e.g. so that $\mathrm{d}(u(x))$ actually means something rather than being a weird shorthand). But when you have that comfort, it is very convenient!

Comment: its just a way to show what I mark as an entity with a different name